# How to add external plug in for CKEditor in Magnolia CMS?

Tags: magnolia

I am trying to customize my CKEditor in Magnolia CMS 5.3.For this i would like to add Font, Color Button to my CKEditor.

I have tried in a way,that i downloaded these plugins and put these plugin.js files in my STK->Resources, I have added the following code in FCKconfig.js file

```
load external plugin
    (function() {
    CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal('font','ckeditor/', 'font-plugin.js');
    CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal('font','ckeditor/', 'color-plugin.js');
})();
```

And also,

```
config.extraPlugins = 'font';
config.extraPlugins = 'colorbutton';
```

But i am getting the default CKEditor instead of Customised one.

Bugs: Image, Hyperlink are not working.

Could you please suggest me?

Answer (score 1):

In the field definition in JCR or YAML for the dialog you can point to a configuration .js file using the configJsFile tag, for example:

```
form:
  tabs:
    - name: tabText
      label: Text
      fields:
        - name: text
          fieldType: richText
          tables: true
          configJSsFile: 'path_to_File'
          height: 500
          label: Text Editor
```

in that file you can change the configuration and add plugins like this:

```
CKEDITOR.plugins.addExternal("plugin_name", CKEDITOR.vaadinDirUrl + "js/plugin_folder/");

CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
  // MIRROR info.magnolia.ui.form.field.definition.RichTextFieldDefinition
  definition = {
    alignment: false,
    images: true,
    lists: true,
    source: true,
    tables: true,
    colors: null,
    fonts: null,
    fontSizes: null
  }


...
...
```

You can check [this](https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS61/Rich+text+field) documentation on Magnolia for more information and this third party tutorial [tutorial](https://www.lars-fischer.me/posts/2016/customize-the-ckeditor-configuration-of-a-magnolia-richtext-field/) for adding the codemirror plugin.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read Magnolia documentation on how to customise ckEditor shipped with Magnolia. https://documentation.magnolia-cms.com/display/DOCS53/Rich+text
What you need to do is re-add `magnolialink` and `magnoliaFileBrowser` plugins in your custom configuration ... and perhaps few other things too.

Comment: Thanks Jan. I did the same thing, I am getting all the tools except font and color. Could you please suggest me?

Comment: If you want same colors and fonts as Magnolia is using while using your own config file, you need to copy them from Magnolia's config into yours.